how to control size of images in quarto html report
I have tried to set image size using the chunk options fig.height and fig-height but the image sizes are unaffected.
---
title: 'image size'
author: 'Joseph Powers'
date: 2024-05-07
format:
    html:
        toc: true
        toc-depth: 3
        html-math-method: webtex
editor: source
fig.align: 'center'
dpi: 300
include: TRUE
echo: FALSE
message: FALSE
warning: FALSE
error: FALSE
cache: FALSE
code-fold: true
df-print: kable
---

```{python}
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *
from mizani.formatters import percent_format
from scipy import stats

my_blue = '#0177c9'
my_red = '#bd0707'

x = np.random.normal(.05, .025, 4000)

# Estimate pdf using kde
pdf = stats.gaussian_kde(x)

# Evaluate pdf at a set of points
points = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)
estimated_density = pdf.evaluate(points)

df_dens = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': points,
    'y': estimated_density
})

p = (ggplot(df_dens, aes('x', 'y')) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_area(data = df_dens[df_dens['x'] >= 0], fill = my_blue) +
 geom_area(data = df_dens[df_dens['x'] <= 0], fill = my_red) +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(panel_grid=element_blank(), axis_text_y=element_blank(), axis_ticks_y=element_blank()) +
 labs(y='', x="\nPlausible Treatment Effects") +
 scale_x_continuous(
    breaks=np.arange(-1, 1.01, 0.01),
    labels=percent_format()
    ) 
)

p
```

```{python}
#| out-width: '20%'
#| out-height: '20%'
p
```

```{python}
#| fig-height: 3
#| fig-width: 10
p
```

```{python, fig.height=1, fig.width=1}
#| fig-height: 1
#| fig-width: 1
p
```



If we look at the figure chunk option list for python cells from Quarto doc, there are no such fig-height, fig-width options listed. And also from previous encounter, I can assume that fig-height, fig-width options do not work as intended for python cells.
Instead, I would suggest using either plotnine theme option theme(figure_size = (a, b)) for a specific plot or the default option plotnine.options.figure_size = (a, b) for all plots.
---
title: 'image size'
author: 'Joseph Powers'
date: 2024-05-07
format:
    html:
        toc: true
        toc-depth: 3
        html-math-method: webtex
editor: source
fig.align: 'center'
dpi: 300
include: TRUE
echo: FALSE
message: FALSE
warning: FALSE
error: FALSE
cache: FALSE
code-fold: true
df-print: kable
---

```{python}
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotnine import *
from scipy import stats

my_blue = '#0177c9'
my_red = '#bd0707'

x = np.random.normal(.05, .025, 4000)

# Estimate pdf using kde
pdf = stats.gaussian_kde(x)

# Evaluate pdf at a set of points
points = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)
estimated_density = pdf.evaluate(points)

df_dens = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': points,
    'y': estimated_density
})

p = (ggplot(df_dens, aes('x', 'y')) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_area(data = df_dens[df_dens['x'] >= 0], fill = my_blue) +
 geom_area(data = df_dens[df_dens['x'] <= 0], fill = my_red) +
 theme_bw()
)

p + theme(figure_size=(2, 2)) # in inches
```


